# How to configure httponly and secure flag in .net core 2.0?

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core, cookie-httponly

There is no error But I am unable to configuration httponly status in browser.
Can you check my code please.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
          });
      }
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       app.UseSession();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
            Secure =CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
            MinimumSameSitePolicy=SameSiteMode.None
        });
      }
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly and specifically you want to do and what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Post the *text* of the exception you're receiving and your code as *text* as well. Images can be used to aid understanding, but your question must be able to stand on its own without them.

Comment: In the chrome browser  Setting-under Advance - content settings - cookies -See all cookies and site data - click in site name Flag are should be - Accessible to script
No (HttpOnly) and Send for
Secure connections only

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) you can configure `HttpOnly` via `IApplicationBuilder.UseCookiePolicy()`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    /*..*/
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you Answer, There is no error But I am still unable to configuration httponly status in browser.

Comment: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
           app.UseSession();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
           
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
                Secure =CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                MinimumSameSitePolicy=SameSiteMode.None
            });
          }

Comment: public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                });
            }

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not post code as a comment. This is unreadable

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, this didn't work when I put it at the end of the Configure method, but did when I moved it higher up.

Comment: @Evan Yes - order matters when using middleware.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core 2.X you can use the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     // This can be removed after https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/371
     services.AddAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
             //Blah Blah Blah
         }).AddCookie(opts =>
         {
              opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
          });
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
 {
     app.UseAuthentication();
 }
```

Note that this changed from ASP.NET Core 1.X